# Program for drawing geometry

Tags: geometry

What program do math teachers use to draw geometry, or what is used in books?
I want the drawing to look **EXACTLY** (I mean the same font and the same line thickness etc.) as in the screenshot I send. Found many programs, but not a one to do it in this way. Please help! Here is the image:

[image]

Comment: Have you noticed the inconsistency with the point denominators? Z and Y are sans-serif, while the rest is in a serif font (it appears to be latex..)

Comment: No, actually haven't. Just searched for an example.

Answer (score 3):

[geogebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GeoGebra) can produce that kind of images, i believe. Other than that, all kinds of vector programs would do (and you are free to change font style, line width, etc.). A popular example is [inkscape](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inkscape).

Answer (score 3):

I think this graphic was created using tikZ, this is a package for LaTeX. It's the standard for the creation of graphics and diagrams in math.
It's not that easy to use, but once you know how to work with it it is pretty powerful!

Answer (score 0):

I usually use this $Free$, $Easy$ and $Powerful$ software:
http://car.rene-grothmann.de/doc_en/download.html

Answer (score 0):

I have not used this program in a few years, so I don't know what changes have occurred lately, but geometer's sketchpad was really nice and probably still is.  It is not free, but there is a free trial I think.

http://www.keycurriculum.com/sketchpad.1.html